# Cisco IP communicator unreliable for incoming calls - IP address conflict?

Tags: ip-address, phone

My workplace uses [Cisco IP communicator](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/voicesw/ps5475/index.html) as a softphone for employees.

I have found it to be quite unreliable for receiving incoming calls.  When my wife calls me, she intermittently gets forwarded straight to my voice-mail (which implies that there is a disconnect between the client and server).  Sometimes she will have to try and call 3-4 times before it starts ringing on my PC.

I suspect this is a flapping issue of some sort where the client is constantly being disconnected from the server for short periods of time, and if the incoming phone call comes at a time when it is connected properly, my phone will ring.

Today when I came into work, there was the following message on my screen:

```
Windows has detected an IP address conflict
...
```

It sounds like this could be connected.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talk to your IT staff - apparently the same ip address is being given to more than one system - this could indicate that someone has your IP address set statically or DHCP is having issues.

If its an issue, its with connectivity with your system as a whole, and is something your admin would need to look into - it WOULD explain the client not working, but there would be other signs - check ipconfig to see if you have a valid ip address and look at the network icon to see if you're connected. Have you had any other issues with your system's network related resources?

Comment: I have had some network flapping in the last few days (where my entire LAN connection would disconnect/reconnect) but this is the first time I have seen this error message.  However, the soft phone has been unreliable for a very long time.

Comment: the network 'flapping' indicates a misconfiguration somewhere - its a definite fixable issue, or at the very least indicates an issue with the network as a whole that needs fixing. as for the softphone issues, there's not enough information to tell what's wrong - i can't seem to find anything on where it'd log things - something your staff will know.